# Unable to connect the appium server "http://127.0.0.1:4788/wd/hub" and "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", method not executing?

Tags: appium

Error in SDK:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce0616068209b10805 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 26.70 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1M92PA5', ip: '10.250.2.20', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:156)
    at Appium.AppiumSetupPage.setUp(AppiumSetupPage.java:43)
    at Appium.C8_Java.main(C8_Java.java:10)
```

Error in Appium Server:

> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce0616068209b10805 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"\nFailed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce0616068209b10805 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce0616068209b10805 install \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk\"\"\nFailed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 26099.816 ms - 1420

Comment: what is your appium version and what is your android device os version

Comment: Appium 1.4.16.1 and Android 7.0

Answer (score 0):

This is the known issue with Android N  (Android 7.0)

you need to either re-install the server (with the --no-shrinkwrap flag) or go into your Appium installation and run the following npm install command.
npm install appium-adb@2.6.13 --no-shrinkwrap

Comment: I have tried the same in Android 6.0.1, but still unable to contact the appium server `code` Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
)

Comment: try to uninstall unlock and appium setting in your phone manually and then run your test again